# UISearchBar gesture recognizer immediately selects cell in tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer, uisearchbar

I got a search bar and a table view setup in my project. Now I want a nice way of dismissing the keyboard just when the user touches the screen anywhere outside of the search bar.

```
//Search bar tap recognizer
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                               initWithTarget:self
                               action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];
[tap setCancelsTouchesInView:NO];
[self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

This works so far - if I leave the following line out:

```
[tap setCancelsTouchesInView:NO];
```

The tap recognizer kind of overlaps the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method so if I wanted to select a row, I had to sort of slide across the cell to trigger the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method.

Anyways with that line if you tap outside of the search bar, the keyboard disappears but the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is also triggered - since most of the time the user would just tap in the middle of the screen - right at a cell of the table view.

How can I keep the table view method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` from being called the first time if the search bar is still "active"? Because I think it's pretty annoying if you just want to dismiss the keyboard and you then the detail view of the tapped cell shows up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
if([self.view isFirstResponder])
{ 
[self.view endEditing:YES];
cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
} else {
cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    //if you have to do some actions when cell is selected
}
}
```

Comment: A little better than the answer above but still - the selected cell gets highlighted and that might cause misunderstandings and functions not being found. Can I stop the cell from getting highlighted if the self.view isFirstResponder?

Comment: Mhh it does not go in if, it's always in the else method... well i'll try if i can fix it myself, thanks for your approach!

Comment: maybe not self.view is the firstResponder, try with: [self isFirstResponder]

Answer (score 0):

In order to  dismiss the keyboard just when the user touches the screen anywhere outside of the search bar, you can call "dismiss keyboard" method  inside table view *didSelectRowAtIndexPath* delegate. So it will work as needed.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     [self dismissKeyboard];
    // you can write detail page navigation code here.
}
```

Comment: Yes but this is exactly what I don't want! The didSelectRowAtIndexPath still gets called and I need a way how I can stop it and just dismiss the keyboard - because I don't want to pick a cell (yet).

Comment: And also this is unfortunate since the cell still gets highlighted --> that's why I do not want the didSelectRowAtIndexPath to be called, any ideas?